# How to write a loop that drops NaN values across multiple pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, nan

I wrote the following code to in python to read multiple csv files into pandas in separate dfs:

```
dfs = []
for f in filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, encoding= 'unicode_escape')
    dfs.append(df)
```

It worked great, and I could index the dfs object I created to access the different dataframes like so:

```
dfs[0], dfs[1], etc
```

However, the dataframes have NaN values in them, and I am trying to write a second loop that will iterate through and drop them. I was sure this would work, however, it did not:

```
for df in dfs:
  df.dropna()
```

The cell ran, but when I called dfs[0], the NaNs were still there. Could this be because the dataframes are in a list? Note, I want to drop rows with Nans, not columns.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign it back

```
for i in range(len(dfs)):
    dfs[i]=dfs[i].dropna()
```

Or add `inplace`

```
for df in dfs:
  df.dropna(inplace=True)
```